# LCOV File has strange Paths at "SF:"

Tags: c++, unit-testing, code-coverage

i am testing my cpp Application with googletest and these part runs very good.
To build and start the Unit-Tests i run a small Powershell Skript.

```
cmake  -G "Unix Makefiles" -S . -B ${BUILD_PATH}
cmake --build $BUILD_PATH
Set-Location $BUILD_PATH
./UnitTests
```

The CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(exampleProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS --coverage)

# GoogleTest
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    googletest
    URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)

set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
enable_testing()

# Testsources
file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES "./test/*.cc")

# Linking
# Add here the "inc" and "src" folder from the features
include_directories(
    "./Example/inc"
    "./Example/src"
    "./test/Example/mock"
)

add_executable(
    unittests 
    ${TEST_SOURCES}
)

target_link_libraries(
    unittests
    gtest_main
    gmock_main
)

include(GoogleTest)

# Run
gtest_discover_tests(unittests)
```

The following Line of Code in my .sh Script works on MacOs perfectly.

```
lcov --directory ${TEST_SOURCE_PATH} --capture --output-file ${LCOV_PATH_INFO} -rc lcov_branch_coverage=1
```

The same i will do on the Windows Machine with this Code in a another Powershell Script:

```
$LCOV = "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\lcov\tools\bin\lcov"
perl $LCOV --capture --directory ${TEST_SOURCE_PATH} --output-file ${LCOV_PATH_INFO}
```

When i run these Script then the .info File has strage Path at the SF-Tag For Example:
SF:C:\dev\exampleProject\build\test\CMakeFiles\unittests.dir\test\Example\C:/Strawberry/c/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/include/c++/ext/alloc_traits.h

The geninfo at the Powershell says me that he cant open these Files, which is logical.

So why i became these stange Paths?

Thank you. Best Guards
Daniel

I read many stuff about this but i found no Solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a Solution with a Powershell Script.

- At first I create a `lcov.info` file.
- After that the created File will be clean about the File Extensions.
- At last I clean the strange Path with the replace Command.

So it works well.